# CoreBluetooth doesn't discover services on reconnect

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

We have an app that is communicating with our own BLE device.  When we push a new firmware we reboot and we get the `centralManager: didDisconnectPeripheral: error:` and the `centralManager: didConnectPeripheral:` but when we call `[peripheral discoverServices:nil]` we never get the callback for `peripheral: didDiscoverServices:`.  We get it when we initially connect but not when we reconnect.  CoreBluetooth seems to know what the services and characteristics are because we can interact with the device but we want to be able to write a characteristic right after the reboot but can't find a reliable way to tell when that is.

-= EDIT =-
This is the code we're using for writing characteristics.  When we try calling it on the second call to `didConnect` it fails because the peripheral doesn't have any services:

```
+(void)writeData:(NSData*)data toPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral service:(NSString*)sCBUUID characteristic:(NSString*)cCBUUID
{
    // Sends data to BLE peripheral to process HID and send EHIF command to PC
    for(CBService *service in peripheral.services)
    {
        if([service.UUID.stringValue isEqualToString:sCBUUID])
        {
            for(CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
            {
                if([characteristic.UUID.stringValue isEqualToString:cCBUUID])
                {
                    /* EVERYTHING IS FOUND, WRITE characteristic ! */
                    [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you read once you get the second call to `didConnectPeripheral`?

Comment: We tried but it fails because the peripheral doesn't know its services at that point.  I updated my question with more information.

Comment: I've had a similar issue. It turned out that iOS was internally caching characteristic descriptors. After the firmware was updated, the descriptors table in the peripheral changed somehow and the phone couldn't discover them anymore (until the phone was rebooted). I'll ask my colleagues working on firmware for further details.

Comment: @MichałCiuba Very cool!  I look forward to hearing your response.

Comment: @CaseyB did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same

Comment: Yes, we did.  We call `NSArray * peripherals = [self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:self.allServices];` which returns a list of devices that CoreBluetooth thinks it's connected to.  Since it has those caches calling discoverServices never actually does anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I remember from my work with CoreBluetooth that this behavior is intended because it's documented this way. We shouldn't reuse the same peripheral instance once disconnected. [Instead we should ask CBCentralManager to give us a fresh CBPeripheral using its known peripheral UUID.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW10) See also: [CBCentralManager.retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals)

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yes, I've rewritten my answer

Comment: Thanks @Lars for rewriting the answer. So, Are services and characteristics caches cleared after disconnect and reconnect ?

Comment: No, the cache is not cleared. Indeed, iOS caches the services and characteristics. It only clears the cache when you restart iOS.

Comment: You however _need_ to get a fresh CBPeripheral once disconnected. Simply call _connect_ on the fresh instance and wait for it to connect. It will connect once it's nearby. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Use case is when peripheral is discovered for first time,app writes some info into one of its characteristics & post writing the peripheral stops advertising service.But app is still subscribed to one of other characteristics & gets notified upon value changes.This works great as long as the app runs in background.But incase of state restoration(in willRestoreState:) I need to get already connected peripheral and subscribe to the characteristic again.

Comment: But nothing happens when I call discoverServices on top of retrieved peripheral.didDiscoverServices: never gets called.services property of retrieved peripheral is null.If iOS caches the services, then retrieved peripheral should still hold the service uuid right?

Comment: When willRestoreState is called, you need to ask for already connected peripherals. Are you retrieving this already?

Comment: yes, of course. `NSArray *peripherals = [self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[ [CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID]]];
self.peripherals = [NSMutableArray new];
for(CBPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals){
    peripheral.delegate = self; 
    [self.peripherals addObject:peripheral];
    NSLog(@"peripheral.services:%@", peripheral.services);    
}`

Comment: When restoring and still connected, services will be there already. Check my wrapper here: https://github.com/getsenic/nuimo-swift/blob/master/SDK/BLEDiscoveryManager.swift and here: https://github.com/getsenic/nuimo-swift/blob/master/SDK/BLEDevice.swift

Comment: Thank you Lars for the wrapper!. Since it is already connected, I just tried disconnecting and reconnecting. It works fine now.